# how can I access this data on data.d.results

Tags: json, rest, vue.js

I am trying to access the Title data found in the image below via rest. Nothing allows me to get it. I have tried:
data.d.results[0].Title
[image]

Comment: Please, first assign your response to a data in the model or a aux var.
Secondly, console log that var, 
And then, try to access like 
console.log(var)
console.log(var.d)
console.log(var.d[0])... etc...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an issue with backlash before double quotes. Tested with: 
`let data = {d: { results: [ { Title: "\"hello\"", } ] }}
console.log(data.d.results[0].Title);`

Worked fine. Can't provide answer without more context

Comment: how can I remove the slashes?

Comment: issue was the data was outputting xml and not json for that specific element